# how to handle mobile back button in .net application

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I have .net website with responsive view. when I open this website in mobile there is no way to close the menu so i want to implement when menu open and user click back button in mobile menu get closed and not to go back page and another condition is without page reloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a # to the URL which you can listen for using window.onhashchange(). You can use location.hash to determine whether to open/close the menu.

Example:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
  var url = location.hash;

  switch(url)
  {
    case "#/open":
      alert('Open menu');
      break;
    default:
      alert('Close menu');
      break;

  }
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/n2xmznbgFJCHOtBVrjjH?p=preview. Click on the link and then press the back button

Comment: please give me proper detail how i implement this

Comment: I believe document.referrer gets you the previous URL. Also I think the only way to clear the last history page is if you intercept the  event and use window.location.replace()